# Proof of the theorem $(p\to\lnot q)\to(q\to\lnot p)$ in Classic logic

Tags: proof-verification, logic, propositional-calculus

Verify if the formula is a theorem in Classic Logic and prove it using the axiomatic system.

> 1. $(p\to\lnot q)\to(q\to\lnot p)$

I verify it and it's a tautology, so it's a theorem.

I also proved it but I didn't use the axiomatic system directly since we have proved in class 7 theorems and I used them to proof 1.

This is the proof I did:

$(p\to\lnot q)\vdash_{CL}(q\to\lnot p)$

by the deduction theorem, we have as hypothesis, $(p\to\lnot q),q$.

By theorem proved in class, $(p\to\lnot q)\to(q\to \lnot p)$ so now we have the result $(q\to \lnot p)$. With $(q\to \lnot p),q$ and Modus ponens, we have $\lnot p$. And again by the deduction theorem, $(q\to\lnot p)$.

Did I solve it correctly ??

Comment: Using the theorem to prove the theorem is quite circular.

Comment: you're right. Haven't notice, actually the proof doesn't have sense then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know *which* axiomatic system you are using, but to prove it by deduction I would assume $p\to\neg q, q,$ and $p$, so as to prove $(p\to \neg q)\to(q\to\neg p)$ via contradiction.

Comment: I see. And then modus ponens with $p\to\neg q, p$, and the result would be $\lnot q$.  And $q\land\lnot q\equiv C$ and there it is the contradiction.